# Performance testing - Jmeter hanged when multiple scenarios added to thread group while performing Load test in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I added the following listed scenarios in the thread group

20 concurrent users checking emails

20 concurrent users replying to emails

20 concurrent users composing new emails

20 concurrent users sending emails with attachments

20 concurrent users making changes to their settings

20 concurrent users doing folder operations

Then I am running these scenarios in the Jmeter but unfortunately the Jmeter gets stuck and remains constant for long time.

How to overcome this, please help this out

Comment: each operation is working on its own? if you use 1 concurrent user the flow works?

Answer (score 0):

"gets strucked" tells nothing to us, we would expect at least essential part of the *jmeter.log* file and details about your [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration and any [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers) used.

In the meantime few recommendations:

1. Make sure you [run your test in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) (120 users is too high for GUI mode)
2. Increase [JVM Heap size allocated to JMeter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm).
3. Remove all the [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) during the test run.
4. Follow [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide.